# DB model for many tables with a zero-to-many relationship to the same table

Tags: sql, database-design, postgresql, polymorphic-associations

I'm creating a DB schema for PostgreSQL 9.0 DB that will represent many real-world entities, with a table per entity. Most of these entities can have 0 or more free-text notes associated with them. A "note" also has some attributes, however, so it would need to be its own table  - I cannot just use an array of strings. So, logically:

```
EntityA -> 0..* Note
EntityB -> 0..* Note
EntityC -> 0..* Note
```

What is the best way to model this in the database?

So far I've come up with 3 alternatives:

1. A column for the ID of each entity type in the Note table, with a foreign key. This is very ugly, because there are many entities.
2. A joining table for each entity table, joining it to Note. This is still ugly, because it doubles the number of tables and may also affect performance (extra join).
3. A generic "entityId" column in the Note table that logically refers to any of the tables, but is not enforced with a foreign key. I can also use the same PostgreSQL sequence for all the entity IDs so that an auto-generated ID is unique for all entities, not just entities of that type. This isn't fool-proof, though, because somebody could still insert an ID manually.

So far I'm leaning towards the 3rd alternative. It keeps the schema clean, but there is no referential integrity, which is not ideal. Could anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Could you give us an idea of how much is "many"? Are there any common columns between entities?

Comment: Perhaps 30-50 entities, possibly more. No, generally no common columns.

Comment: then I would suggest No 3, or modified with generic entity table as described after the edit in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that:

- "Many" is a manageable number of entities (up to you to decide)
- There are some common columns among entities (like `EntityName`)
- One note belongs to one entity only, one entity can have many notes.

You could try something like

[image]

**EDIT**

In the next scenario, the `Entity` table has only `EntityID` and `EntityType`, while each `E_Type_X` table has all columns. The only purpose of the `Entity` table is to generate unique keys which are then propagated to each  `E_Type_X` table. Because of the key propagation, each `E_Type_X` table can be directly joined to the `Notes` table.

This is a logical equivalent of all `E_Type_X` tables using the same sequence for the key generation -- so close to your solution No 3, but all foreign key constraints can be implemented.

Comment: Hmm, this might be just about there. I tried something *almost* like this, but with each entity table *inheriting* from a base Entity table. However, I found that creating a FK from Note to the base Entity table didn't allow Notes for rows in derived tables - which is a documented limitation of PostgreSQL inheritance. Your alternative with a FK instead of inheritance might just work, though. The only thing it doesn't do is cascade deletes, so I could delete E_Type_1, while leaving its Entity row and therefore its Notes, but maybe a trigger could fix that. I'll give this a try.

Comment: And wow, you drew a diagram for me! I'd give you an extra +1 just for that, if I could.

Comment: @EMP you could (should) implement deletes starting from `Entity` table, that would cascade.

Answer (score 2):

As a 4th alternative you could consider having a note table for each entity table (whose foreign key back to the associated entity table would be correct).  The disadvantage of this is that you have more than one note table (one extra table per entity table, to be precise).

Is that going to be a problem?  It can really depend on what is accessing this database.  If it is an application, the application itself can be coded to determine the correct notes table to go with an entity table at any particular time.

I don't think this option is any worse than having a foreign key and a "which entity table" type field in a single notes table.  At least constraints would be enforced.

Comment: Option 2 is the best regarding normalization. Keeps all referential integrity checks one wants and still has one Note table. Option 4,  is almost as good but you have to maintain a lot of Note tables. So, if you want to alter the structure of Notes (like adding a field), you have to alter all those tables.

Comment: If that is not clear, I would still choose Option 4 over the other two (1 and 3).

Answer (score 1):

I would go for option 2, as it is a more normalized structure,
and I would not worry about the join.

If you are worried about it looking 'ugly' simply create a view.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided not to create any new tables for this and created some rules instead. However, I'm accepting **Damir Sudrevic**'s answer, because it's the closest to what I wanted (and I love the fact that he drew a diagram for me!)

Essentially there were two problems I wanted to solve:

1. Ensure that when an Entity is deleted so are all of its Notes.
2. Ensure that a Note cannot be created without referencing a valid entity.

The first problem was solved by creating a rule for each entity (which I could script if I get to enough entities):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE rl_somentity_delete_note
AS ON DELETE TO someentity
DO ALSO DELETE FROM note WHERE entity_id = OLD.id
```

The second problem was not solved. I decided that I'd rather take the (low) risk of users creating "orphaned" notes than complicate the schema with an extra table and extra FK for each entity table, which would require an extra `INSERT` statement to add each entity row.